# What format should I use to show 2 decimals or none?

Tags: java, decimal, printf

I'm trying to format a number using printf but can't find the correct mask.

For instance:

```
class F { 
    public static void main( String ... args ) { 
        p(2.123123);
        p(2.0);
    }
    public static void p(double d ) { 
        System.out.printf("%.2f",d);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Will print:

```
2.12
2.00
```

What mask should I use to make it print

```
2.12
2
```

Or if possible:

```
2.12
   2
```

?

Background:

I'll use this to display file sizes. Currently looks like this:

```
23/03/11 12:15 0.00    TEST/
30/03/11 10:35 2.57 kb picture-3651.jpg
12/04/11 14:49 7.31 mb reference.pdf
```

Which, needless to say looks terrible when the file is a directory and its size is 0 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `DecimalFormat` does it:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
```

Comment: So, that should be something like: `printf("%s %s %s,df.format(humanSize(file.length()),humanDesc(file.length()), file.getName())` ? ...  I was feeling dirty already by having to invoke an extra function to the the size and description already, but I guess there is no other option.

Comment: @noob - what did you mean by that?

Comment: @Bozho: That you provided a good (and easy to understand) solution.

Comment: It does not work for 2.9. Formatting it will not display "2.90" So any solution that works for all cases, providing two decimals or none? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might try experimenting with `%.3g`, it should do roughly what you are looking for, but includes the numbers to the left of the `.` in the mask.

If that doesn't work for you, you can also just search for `.00` and strip it out using `String.replace`.

EDIT after some experimentation:

`String.format("%.2f\n", value).replace(".00", "")` should do what you are looking for.

Comment: Looks the same to me... TEST folder size is 0.00 :(